# Programmatically create EC2 instance, run command, and terminate

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I seek a method to implement a cron-like system on AWS EC2 instance : every morning, I have some tasks to run, and they are using a lot of RAM (about 8 Go for each script). I don't want to pay a full-time `c4.2xlarge` instance, that's the point.

What I think about :

1. At 00h, each day, create a `c4.2xlarge` instance
2. When the system is running, run a PHP script
3. When the PHP script ends, terminate the instance

How to automate these actions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created an instance with `--instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate` then it will terminate itself when stopped. All you need to do is run `shutdown -h now` at the end of your script when it's done.

So how do you start an instance at a specific time?

1. There are third party services that do exactly that. Like GorillaStack.

OR

2. Create a [CloudWatch scheduled event](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html). It's basically a `cron` in the cloud that can run a Lambda function, which in turn may start you instance.

Comment: Didn't knew about GorillaStack, seems great, i'll try it ! Thanks Sergey !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you intend to do in your cron scripts, but look at AWS Lambda [scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

Note that Lambda does not natively support PHP, but there appear to be [options](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/). Personally, I'd consider rewriting it in Python or JavaScript if possible.

Comment: It's some MongoDB related tasks : grab data in various places and modify existant documents (but for laaaaaaarge data sets)

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

Just Create a c4.2xlarge Instance with all the Configuration Defined.

While you launch the instance, Create a “user-data script” in the advanced tab, So that it runs the script after launch of the instance and issues a terminate command to itself after the job is done..

To call the launching script, you can set a cron job either locally or use aws lambda.